Working with actions as aset, when using NLA and asset managmet, unespect keys are added during action assigment in blender 4.3
I am trying to make following.
I have generated rig of human using metahuman and rigify.
When I am creating isolated action( only single rotation or location chage for example fingers close) with action editor. And then when I am trying to add it to NLA, additional key frames are added, furhter more they are directrly added to asset library and changing action it self. Sometimes the additional keyframes are scale, in or out like in the picture or unaused location position. I am creating initial keyframes by slecting fingers contrlos hiting K and select rotation only. And in the action they look like this until I am transfering back to action editor with assign action. Am I missing somthing ( should I lock somehow action before importing it in NLA)  or there is a bug and I should reported it.

Some additional info. After some investigation the new keyframes appear in  the moment of creating a new Pose Asset in Action editor. It adds additional Scale, Rotation and Location keyframes to the Bone + In and Out keyframes. If you delete them manualy afterwards you can save clean asset. For me this is unwanted behaviour it could be a bug or setting.
